# The logic behind SQL NULL comparisont

Tags: sql

I'm not sure how to implement SQL NULL comparison in my query.

Example 1:

```
select case when null > null then 1 
            when null < null then 2 
            when null > 1 then 4
            when null < 1 then 5
            else 3 end as test;
```

The result I expect is 5,
but I get 3.

Example 2:

```
select case when null < 1 then 5
            else 3 end as test;
```

The result should be five, yet I'm getting three.

Can someone explain my issue?

Comment: Put simply Null requires a special equality check in SQL using `is null` or `is not null` to check for null.  Typical equality checks to values that can be null will result in evaluations to Null (not true, not false).

Comment: So your expectation is NULL should be treated as 0?  in most RDBMS Null means a value hasn't been set for a record yet.  The user/system hasn't received/defined a value for the row/column involved.  Thus the value is Null until such time that value is set.  Treating Null as 0 is also dangerous if the datatype being compared to is character data instead of numeric; or date instead of numeric.  which when dealing with outer joins in a RDBMS and comparing nulls can/will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

No, the result should not be `5`.  SQL is correct.

Almost any comparison with `NULL` returns `NULL` -- that includes:

```
 null < 1
 null > 1
 null = 1
 null <> 1
```

And `NULL` is not considered "true", so `where` and `when` clauses filter it out.

If you want to treat `null` as `0`, then use `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(null, 0) < 5
```

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` has a value which is UNKNOWN.

Let's think:

- `when null > null` - Is an unknown value greater than another unknown value? This is unknown, i.e. `null > null` == `NULL`.
- `when null > 1` - Is an unknown value greater than `1`? This is unknown, i.e. `null > 1` == `NULL`.

And so on...

Almost all comparisons or other operations with `NULL` (addition, concatenation and so on) give `NULL` - when an operand is unknown then the result is not defined, so the result is unknown.

When the expression is finally `NULL` then it is treated as `FALSE` - because nobody can guarantee that this `UNKNOWN` is `TRUE`.

There are a couple of exceptions, of course. Operator `IS` tests for `NULL` correctly: `null IS NULL` == `TRUE`. In MySQL there is null-safe compare operator `<=>`, which assumes that all `NULL`s are equal.

Comment: "When the expression is finally NULL then it is treated as FALSE" isn't quite right... It treats it as NULL.  Don't believe me?  Here's an example on SQL Server: https://rextester.com/LZUI53379  I use a case statement to check  not null vs null looking for a false or true; both return null!  pretty sure this applies to most common RDBMS.

Comment: @xQbert There is no an action for NULL/UNKNOWN final value - only TRUE alternative/action or FALSE alternative/action. When final result is NULL than FALSE alternative is selected / action is performed. Or, maybe, you know SQL operator/expression which realizes tri-logic?

Comment: @xQbert *Here's an example on SQL Server: rextester.com/LZUI53379 I use a case statement to check not null vs null looking for a false or true; both return null!* Sorry, but you tell about something unrelative, your example is incorrect - it demonstrates that when CASE function have no ELSE and none expression matches then NULL is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions with null values usually return null. However, there are a few exceptions, for example:

`null OR TRUE` => `TRUE`

`null AND FALSE` => `FALSE`

`null IS DISTINCT FROM null` => `FALSE`

`null IS DISTINCT FROM 'A'` => `TRUE`

`null IS NOT DISTINCT FROM null` => `TRUE`

`null IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'A'` => `FALSE`

`null IS NULL` => `TRUE`

`null IS NOT NULL` => `FALSE`

`1 BETWEEN 2 AND null` => `FALSE`

`1 NOT BETWEEN 2 AND null` => `TRUE`

`NOT null IS NOT NULL` => `TRUE` (As suggested by Akina)

Comment: @Akina, `TRUE`.

Comment: Of course... one of standard questions for operator precedence knowledge testing...